# Ruby require a code snippet from github

Tags: ruby

Is there anyway to get Ruby's require statement to download a file from somewhere like github rather than just the local file system?

Update: Sorry I should have made the question clearer. I want to download a file that contains Ruby module and import it into my script rather than just downloading an image or some other arbitrary file within my script.

In other words something like this

```
require 'http:\\github.com\myrepo\snippet.rb'

puts 'hi'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, this is not possible. Also, it's not a good idea for security reasons.

You have a couple of alternatives. If the file you want to include is a Gem and Git repository, then you can use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to download and package the dependency in your project. Then you'll be able to `require` the file directly in your source code.

This is the best and safest way to include an external dependency.

If you trust the source and you really know what you are doing, you can download the file using Net::HTTP (or any other HTTP library) and eval the body directly in your Ruby code.
You can package everything in a custom `require_remote` function.

Comment: As noted, the snippet would have to be in a repo with a gemspec for bundler to require it. e.g. gem 'snippets', :git => 'http://github.com/myrepo/snippets.git'

Answer (score 3):

You could download and eval it

```
require "open-uri"

alias :require_old :require

def require(path)
    return false if $".include?(path)
    unless path=~ /\Ahttp:\/\/
        return require_old(path)
    end
    eval(open(path).read)
    $"<< path
    true
end
```

Be aware, this code has no error checking for network outages nonexisting files, ... . I also believe it is in general not a good idea to require libraries this way, there are security and reliability problems in this approach. But maybe you have a valid usecase for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can include a remote gem from within `Gemfiles` then it will download when you run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question and answers I wanted something a little more bullet proof and verbose that used a paradigm of creating a local file from a repo and then requiring it, only if it didn't already exist locally already. The request for the repo version is explicit via the method `repo_require`. Used on files you control, this approach improves security IMO.

```rb
# try local load
def local_require(filename, relative_path)
  relative_flname = File.join(relative_path, filename)
  require_relative(relative_flname)
end

# try loading locally first, try repo version on load error
# caution: only use with files you control access to!
def repo_require(raw_repo_prefix, filename, relative_path = '')
  local_require(filename, relative_path)

rescue LoadError => e
  puts e.message
  require 'open-uri'

  tempdir = Dir.mktmpdir("repo_require-")
  temp_flname = File.join(tempdir, File.basename(filename))
  return false if $LOADED_FEATURES.include?(temp_flname)

  remote_flname = File.join(raw_repo_prefix, filename)
  puts "file not found locally, checking repo: #{remote_flname}"
  begin
    File.open(temp_flname, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(URI.parse(remote_flname).read)
    end
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
    raise "Error: Can't load #{filename} from repo: #{e.message} - #{remote_flname}"
  end
  require(temp_flname)
  FileUtils.remove_entry(tempdir)
end
```

Then you could call `repo_require` like this:

```rb
repo_require('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/reponame/branch',
             'filename', 'relative_path')
```

The `relative_path` would the the relative path you would use for the file if the repo was locally installed. For example, you may have something like `require_relative '../lib/utils.rb'`. In this example `filename='lib/utils.rb'` and `relative_path='..'`. This information allows the repo url to be constructed correctly as it does not use the relative path portion.